# prevent nginx to handle subset url

Tags: nginx, symfony

I run an Angular app rendered from a Symfony controller. My symfony application is based on `http://localhost/portal` and has a route on `http://localhost/portal/shop/` (wich renders the Angular app).

My current nginx configuration works well for this url.

When I reach `http://localhost/portal/shop/.*` I want that nginx runs the Symfony app on the controller `http://localhost/portal/shop/` and let the rest of the uri be handled by Angular routing.

My nginx knowledge are limited. Is that possible ? If yes, how can it be achieved?

My current location to handle `/portal/shop` is :

```
location /portal {
    root $projectroot/portal/web;
    rewrite ^/portal/?(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 break;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $projectroot/portal/web/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
}
```

Let me know if you need more of my config file. It's pretty big as it also handle an api section ;-)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, it's possible and without more information I'd even say the config you posted "should work". Maybe it would be useful to update the question with a description of the problems you have encountered when trying that?encountered?

Comment: Sorry @shevron, I havn't seen your comment... Not used to stackexchange format... See my response below, I make it worked. I took the problem to a too deep level. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution without nginx. My mind might be blocked at a certain point.

Based on the solution provided in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37404984/3258993) I made this:

```php
class ShopController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/shop/{angularRoute}", name="shop", requirements={"angularRoute": ".*"})
     */
    public function __invoke() {
        return $this->render('shop.html');
    }
}
```